# Установка PostreSQL на Windows 2008 r2

Tags: postgresql, windows-server-2008-r2

Пытаюсь поставить PostreSQL 10.9 на Win 2008 r2 x64.

В конце установки постоянно вываливается ошибка инициализации кластера. Как итог папка data пустая, пользователь postgres не создаётся, служба postgresql-x64-10 не появляется.

Нашёл много топиков, в которых советовали ставить не в Program Files, докидывать права вручную и реинсталить, инсталить от имени вручную созданного юзера postgres с правами всемогущего — не спасло ничего.

Сообщение в конце установки выглядит вот так:

> Problem running post-install step: The database cluster init failed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спасла статья с хабра:

https://habr.com/ru/post/101678/

Коротко, батник:

```
@ECHO ON
@SET PATH="%CD%\bin";%PATH%
@SET PGDATA=%CD%\data
@SET PGDATABASE=postgres
@SET PGUSER=postgres
@SET PGPORT=5439
@SET PGLOCALEDIR=%CD%\share\locale
REM %CD%\bin\initdb -U postgres -A trust
%CD%\bin\pg_ctl -D %CD%/data -l logfile start
ECHO "Нажмите Enter чтобы остановить работу сервера"
pause
%CD%\bin\pg_ctl -D %CD%/data stop
```

При первом старте раскоментить строку:
`REM %CD%\bin\initdb -U postgres -A trust`

После закоментить и стартовать сервак через этот батник.

Comment: Качается zip, не инсталер.

Comment: Батник в корень содержимого зипа.